# MSAccess - Date/Time Formatting - Losing Leading Zero

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access table with a Date/Time attribute (single field) formatted as:

`"mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss"`

I am importing/appending the data from an XLS file (via transferspreadsheet), the resulting value does not include the leading zero on HOUR.

`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "myImport", strFilename, True`

`XLS Data
2017-3-28 07:22
2017-3-28 07:42
2017-3-28 07:41`

`Access imported/appended result
03/28/2017 7:22:05
03/28/2017 7:42:53
03/28/2017 7:41:00`

I do not own or control the XLS datasheet.

Is there any way to force the leading zero on data during import/append?

Answer (score 0):

If you import correctly, you import date/time *values*.

These carry *no format*, so what you see in Access is determined by your Windows settings. If you want anything else, apply a format of your choice to the *Format* property of the fields or textboxes where you display the values, like:

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:nn:ss
```